# Convert custom model to XML string with SimpleXmlConverter or by any other library?

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

I'm working with Retrofit2 and SimpleXmlConverter to call the APIs. The request and response is based on the XML data. I need to send XML string with tags in the request body.

By using SimpleXmlConverter, I can easily parse XML response into my custom models but I can't able to convert my custom model into XML string like we do with JsonConverters.

Is there any way to convert my custom model into XML string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Serializer class of SimpleXmlConverter library you can do the parsing. Refer below code:

This is the custom model class

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "notification", strict = false)
public class NotificationModel {

    @Element(name = "code")
    public String errorCode;

    @Element(name = "message")
    public String errorMessage;
}
```

This is the xml string which you want to parse into the model

```
<notification xmlns:d="http://www.website.com/pref/data">
    <code>004</code>
    <message>Error during value update</message>
    <severity>info</severity>
    <target />
</notification>
```

Use the below code to parse the above xml string

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

String xmlString = "above xml string"
try {
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    NotificationModel notificationModel = serializer.read(NotificationModel.class, xmlString);
    //TODO: Use notificationModel's variables with filled values
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```